# JHipster with kafka real app usage example

Tags: apache-kafka, jhipster, reactor-kafka

In **JHipster** version **6.6.0** the Kafka usage model has been changed from the standard Producer/Consumer classes to the WebResource level. There are no real examples what is an advantage of this change and how this change can be used in real apps.

Let`s say we have **Service A** and **Service B**. The communication between these two services has to be accomplished via Kafka events.

The question is - what I have to do so **Service B** starts to listen to events from the **Service A** topic. In the current configuration, it looks like I have to manually trigger `/consumes` endpoint, but it makes no sense because I'm expecting that the service will start to listen for the specified list of topics after the app is up and running.

I would appreciate any comment on this topic to help me understand this.

Example:
jhipster 7.1.0 generates this resources:

Service A - *gateway*

```java
package com.stukans.refirmware.gateway.web.rest;

import com.stukans.refirmware.gateway.config.KafkaProperties;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions;
import reactor.kafka.sender.KafkaSender;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderOptions;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderRecord;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderResult;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/gateway-kafka")
public class GatewayKafkaResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayKafkaResource.class);

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
    private KafkaSender<String, String> sender;

    public GatewayKafkaResource(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
        this.sender = KafkaSender.create(SenderOptions.create(kafkaProperties.getProducerProps()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/publish/{topic}")
    public Mono<PublishResult> publish(
        @PathVariable String topic,
        @RequestParam String message,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String key
    ) {
        log.debug("REST request to send to Kafka topic {} with key {} the message : {}", topic, key, message);
        return Mono
            .just(SenderRecord.create(topic, null, null, key, message, null))
            .as(sender::send)
            .next()
            .map(SenderResult::recordMetadata)
            .map(
                metadata ->
                    new PublishResult(metadata.topic(), metadata.partition(), metadata.offset(), Instant.ofEpochMilli(metadata.timestamp()))
            );
    }

    @GetMapping("/consume")
    public Flux<String> consume(@RequestParam("topic") List<String> topics, @RequestParam Map<String, String> consumerParams) {
        log.debug("REST request to consume records from Kafka topics {}", topics);
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = kafkaProperties.getConsumerProps();
        consumerProps.putAll(consumerParams);
        consumerProps.remove("topic");

        ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(consumerProps).subscription(topics);
        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions).receive().map(ConsumerRecord::value);
    }

    private static class PublishResult {

        public final String topic;
        public final int partition;
        public final long offset;
        public final Instant timestamp;

        private PublishResult(String topic, int partition, long offset, Instant timestamp) {
            this.topic = topic;
            this.partition = partition;
            this.offset = offset;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
    }
}
```

Service B - *agent*

```java
package com.stukans.refirmware.agent.web.rest;

import com.stukans.refirmware.agent.config.KafkaProperties;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.KafkaReceiver;
import reactor.kafka.receiver.ReceiverOptions;
import reactor.kafka.sender.KafkaSender;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderOptions;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderRecord;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderResult;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/agent-kafka")
public class AgentKafkaResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AgentKafkaResource.class);

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;
    private KafkaSender<String, String> sender;

    public AgentKafkaResource(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
        this.sender = KafkaSender.create(SenderOptions.create(kafkaProperties.getProducerProps()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/publish/{topic}")
    public Mono<PublishResult> publish(
        @PathVariable String topic,
        @RequestParam String message,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String key
    ) {
        log.debug("REST request to send to Kafka topic {} with key {} the message : {}", topic, key, message);
        return Mono
            .just(SenderRecord.create(topic, null, null, key, message, null))
            .as(sender::send)
            .next()
            .map(SenderResult::recordMetadata)
            .map(
                metadata ->
                    new PublishResult(metadata.topic(), metadata.partition(), metadata.offset(), Instant.ofEpochMilli(metadata.timestamp()))
            );
    }

    @GetMapping("/consume")
    public Flux<String> consume(@RequestParam("topic") List<String> topics, @RequestParam Map<String, String> consumerParams) {
        log.debug("REST request to consume records from Kafka topics {}", topics);
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = kafkaProperties.getConsumerProps();
        consumerProps.putAll(consumerParams);
        consumerProps.remove("topic");

        ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(consumerProps).subscription(topics);
        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions).receive().map(ConsumerRecord::value);
    }

    private static class PublishResult {

        public final String topic;
        public final int partition;
        public final long offset;
        public final Instant timestamp;

        private PublishResult(String topic, int partition, long offset, Instant timestamp) {
            this.topic = topic;
            this.partition = partition;
            this.offset = offset;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }
    }
}
```

That`s the only code related to Kafka that is available.

Prior to version 6.6.0, *JHipster* generated standard Producer/Consumer classes which I could use to define which topics to listen to. Now it is not clear how to use generated code to emit/listen to the events.

Answer (score 0):

First, since we cannot see your code, we don't know how it does (or should) work...

In any case, you should not be "triggering" consumers via REST; they should be automatically started when the service starts. If there are no messages, then they are polling in the background and idling until the "producer service" pushes a message to the topic.

Comment: I have updated my question with an example, hope it will help. I understand how the producer/consumer patterns work. With my question I wanted to figure out what stands behind the change made by the JHipster team and how I should use it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JHipster, but if you want to ask about their changes, perhaps a Github issue (or whatever they use for support) would be best... Otherwise, you can check the Spring Webflux / Project Reactor documentation to see how it should be used with Kafka. Regarding "how to use it", seems like you issue a GET with a list of topics to the endpoint, with consumer properties, then that will generate a streaming HTTP response with the records returned

Answer (score 0):

I make a service like this auto triggering consumers:

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumerService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumerService.class);

    private static final String GROUP_USER_CREATE_TOPIC = "GROUP_STORE.GROUP_USER.SAVE"; //<application name>.<dataset name>.<event>

    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    private KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private final GroupMemberService groupMemberService;

    public KafkaConsumerService(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, GroupMemberService groupMemberService) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
        this.groupMemberService = groupMemberService;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        log.info("Kafka consumer starting...");
        Map<String, Object> consumerProps = kafkaProperties.getConsumerProps();
        ReceiverOptions<String, String> receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(consumerProps)
            .subscription(Collections.singletonList(GROUP_USER_CREATE_TOPIC));
        this.kafkaReceiver = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions);
        consumeGroupMember().subscribe();
    }

    public Flux<GroupMemberDTO> consumeGroupMember() {
        log.debug("consumer group member....");
        return this.kafkaReceiver
            .receive()
            .map(ConsumerRecord::value)
            .flatMap(
                record -> {
                    try {
                        GroupMemberDTO groupMemberDTO = objectMapper.readValue(record, GroupMemberDTO.class);
                        log.debug("Complete convert object: {}", groupMemberDTO);
                        return groupMemberService.insert(groupMemberDTO);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            );
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        log.info("Shutdown kafka consumer");
    }
}
```